# Computing fundamental group of a circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm very new to Topology but we just covered in class an algorithm for calculating the Fundamental Group of a surface given a triangulation. The algorithm goes as follows:

1) Find a spanning tree in the triangulation

2) Add in 2-simplices where two sides are already in the tree

3) Repeat two until you have a maximal simply connected subcomplex

4) Use relations given by the 2-simplices to determine the group.

So given this and the triangulation of S1:
[S1 Triangulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC5ff.png)

I get [the spanning tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQIaM.png)

Now am I right in thinking that the algorithm doesn't work in the next step because the interior of the circle is not in the surface, [so the following is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJli5.png)

Whereas the correct continuation would be to pass over step 2 (and 3) to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPUWV.png)

Which would mean that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is just $\langle a\rangle  = F^{1} \cong \mathbb{Z}$, and not the trivial group?

Comment: Thank you for the downvote and tip regarding formatting, I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: I did the formatting edit, but I did not provide the downvote. (According to my profile, I've cast a grand total of 36 downvotes since starting 8 years and 7 months ago, so you can probably guess that I am parsimonious with them...)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism all the same! I greatly appreciate it.